# How to query google drive API by file ID?

Tags: python, google-api

I don't see a way to query google drive API by file ID. Is there a way to do so?

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref

Answer (score 2):

You can query files by `fileId` using below API -

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId`

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get